# google compute ssh keys username issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a need to manage my own ssh keys to log into virtual machines.  So I did the ssh-keygen from my home pc ("jepp") and loaded that into the google project metadata.  Here's the format of the public key:

```
ssh-rsa [ASCII KEY] user1@jepp
```

Now google says to append your google account username (say mine is "user2") so what goes into the metadata ssh field is as follows:

```
user2:ssh-rsa [ASCII KEY] user1@jepp
```

It looks like the page auto-parses out the username, and (incorrectly, i think) picks user1.  When I try to ssh into the box, this is returned:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Now if I redo this whole process, but instead create a username on my local machine that matches my google username, it works.  In other words my ssh key looks like this:

```
user2:ssh-rsa [ASCII KEY] user2@jepp
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Did you tried https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/user-accounts/?hl=en_US&_ga=1.50592865.91415260.1429824108 ? So you can add keys via `gcloud beta compute users add-keys`

Comment: Are you trying to add the keys on the Instance's metadata or project's metadata?
When you add the SSH Key what is the username that appears on the page?
I followed the same steps you mentioned and it worked.
Can you can check if the "user1" was created on the machine?

Comment: I'm trying to add to the Project's metadata.  The username appearing next to my key is user1, that's what I think the problem is. My google username is user2 and there's already an account on the VM under user2.  The only reason user1 comes into play is because thats the account on my home machine.  I shouldn't have to create a user1 on the google VM or a user2 on my home machine, but thats my only work-around right now.